# how to get a parameter from dynamic url in asp.net MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following url

`http://localhost/user/MyUserName`

How do I get "MyUserName" from that url? So I can use it at the server side to retrieve the information I want to present to the client side?

In Django it was very simply to archive that. But how do I do that in ASP.net MVC4?

**EDIT**

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
```

Comment: MyUserName is always the last 'parameter' in the url?

Comment: @Exsaliver no that is the dynamic part of the url. It can be anything. But I want that parameter so I can fetch the userdata from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what did you name your route parameter

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
     new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}, 
     null,
     new[] {"Project.Web.Controllers"});
```

But I suppose it's `Id` anyway try this:

```
var value = RouteData.Values["Id"];
```

---

***Update :***

In your case you should define a special route **before " on top of " the default one** :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ForUser",
    "User/{id}", 
     new {controller = "User", action = "UserInfo", id = UrlParameter.Optional}, 
     null,
     new[] {"Project.Web.Controllers"});
```

Comment: Okay, it is possible to get `MyUserName` if the url looks something like this `http://localhost/User/UserInfo/MyUserName`. Where `User` is the controller, and `UserInfo` is the action. But can I get my wanted parameter without the need of that extra part in the url?

Comment: I just want it to be `http://localhost/User/MyUserName`, but I don't want to change the route part.